# Upload Image to Azure Blob container using Axios [VueJs]

Tags: javascript, html, azure, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to using Axios **PUT** function to upload an image to **Azure Storage**.

What I did is as following:

1. I created a storage account in Azure, then I Add CORS rule as following: [CORS rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XT8gJ.jpg)
2. I created a Blob with name `user-pic`.
3. I use *Axios* to make the request for me

**code:**

```
function upload(formData) {

    //get the current date
    var currentdate = new Date(); 
    var Curr_date = currentdate.getDay + '-' + currentdate.getMonth + '-' + currentdate.getFullYear; 

    //Here I am trying to convert the image to binary encoding.
    var data = btoa(formData);

    //The image Url, [ below there is an example from where I take this url ].
    const url = "https://XXXXXXX.blob.core.windows.net/XXXXXXXXXXXX";

    //Headers are required for me, do I need to add all Headers in my code also in CORS of the storage account?
    axios.put(url, data {
          headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*",
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS',
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, Content-Type, x-ms-*",
            "Content-Type": "image/png",
            "Content-Length": data.length, //here I am trying to get the size of image.
            "x-ms-date": Curr_date,
            "x-ms-version": sv,
            "x-ms-blob-type": "BlockBlob",
          }            
        })
        .then ( response => { console.log(response); console.log('correct!!'); } )
        .catch ( error => { console.log(error); console.log('error here!!'); });
}
```

What I mean by the comments inside the code:

1. The image URL should be at the same format of this: [Blob SAS Url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFIpk.jpg)
2. Is the format of `Curr_date` is correct to be accepted by `x-ms-date` header?
3. Is function `btoa` used to convert the image to binary encoding?
4. Should I add all headers in Axios into account storage CORS (in the header field)?
5. What is the correct method to get the size of the image? (`.size` function? actually, I am passing the `formData` after appending all images into it.

After running the program, in the console, I got two error messages: [image: Error Messages]

How can I solve these problems?

**Update:**

I made these changes:

1. I change the CORS: [CORS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzJ1k.png)
2. I got this error msg: [Error Msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmqEO.png)

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-*` are **response** headers, not request headers.

Comment: @evilSnobu what do you mean about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CORS rule defined for your Azure Storage is missing your http://localhost origin.

Comment: you mean I should add all the headers in Axios inside the headers of storge CORS?

Comment: No, I mean you have to add your localhost origin to the Allowed origin within your Azure Storage Account (in the Portal)

Comment: you mean my IP address so it can access my localhost?

Comment: No, I mean the origin, similar as you already did here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XT8gJ.jpg

Comment: I added my localhost there, but I faced another error message: `403 (Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.)` .

Comment: Please change your CORS settings in the portal and set * for both request and response headers.

Comment: I edit the question, and add the changes .. but still, I have the same problem.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the **exact CORS settings** that you have in the Azure Portal. Currently the screenshot you shared has incorrect CORS settings. The issue you're facing is most likely because of incorrect CORS settings.

Comment: The problem, I don't know how to add the correct CORS? can you help me what should I add exactly in each field?

Comment: Try these values: `*` for `Allowed Origins`, `Allowed Headers` and `Exposed Headers`. Select all verbs for `Allowed Verbs`.

Comment: I change the values in Azure, and run the program same error msg .. after that, I change the values of [ `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*", 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': '*', "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*",` ] but same error message :)